# LNK 2001 error with struct

Tags: visual-c++, struct, lnk2001

I have a h- and a cpp-file with some calculations used in many of my projects.

Now I tried to put them in a separate dll, so the files should not be included in every project.

When linking I get a LNK2001 (unresolved symbol) error for a struct, however lib and dll are in the right place.

I use the

```
#ifdef TOOLS_EXPORTS
#define TOOLS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TOOLS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

macro, which works fine for a couple of methods.

The struct is defined like that

```
TOOLS_API typedef  struct  {
char Name[128];
}  uTSystem;
```

And in the files using this struct from the dll its also defined correctly(?)

```
extern uTSystem ABC;
```

The error message is:

```
error LNK2001: Nichtaufgeloestes externes Symbol "struct uTSystem ABC" (?ABC@@3UuTSystem@@A)
```

Any hints? Thank you

Comment: Do you get the LINK2001 when linking the DLL or the consuming application? It may also be helpful to include the exact error message.

Comment: I get the error, when linking the dll

Comment: the error message is: error LNK2001: Nichtaufgeloestes externes Symbol "struct uTSystem ABC" (?ABC@@3UuTSystem@@A)

Comment: extern uTSystem ABC; in the class using this struct was wrong; uTSystem ABC; is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you defined TOOLS_EXPORT when compile the DLL you will export the variable `ABC`. In your code you define it as `extern uTSystem ABC;` That's ok for the header file, that you share with the consuming DLL.

While the extern declares that there is a variable ABC you must define it in one of your .cpp file:

```
uTSystem ABC;
```

without the `extern` in front. Your file might look like this:

---- tools.h ----

```
#ifdef TOOLS_EXPORTS
#define TOOLS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TOOLS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

TOOLS_API typedef  struct  {
char Name[128];
}  uTSystem;

extern uTSystem ABC;
```

---- tools.cpp ----

```
#include tools.h

uTSystem ABC;
```